# SQL: Arrange numbers on a scale 1 to 10

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, where-clause, min

I have a table in a SQL Server 2008 database with a number column that I want to arrange on a scale 1 to 10.

Here is an example where the column (`Scale`) is what I want to accomplish with SQL

```
Name    Count   (Scale)
----------------------
A       19      2       
B       1       1
C       25      3
D       100     10
E       29      3
F       60      7
```

In my example above the min and max count is 1 and 100 (this could be different from day to day).

I want to get a number to which each record belongs to.

```
1 = 0-9
2 = 10-19
3 = 20-29 and so on...
```

It has to be dynamic because this data changes everyday so I can not use a `WHERE` clause with static numbers like this: `WHEN Count Between 0 and 10...`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this, though note technically the value 100 doesn't fall in the range 90-99 and therefore should probably be classed as 11, hence why the value 60 comes out with a scale of 6 rather than your 7:

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d41d8/41244)

**MS SQL Server 2008 Schema Setup**:

**Query 1**:

```
create table #scale
(
    Name Varchar(10),
    [Count] INT
)

INSERT INTO #scale
VALUES
    ('A', 19),
    ('B', 1),
    ('C', 25),
    ('D', 100),
    ('E', 29),
    ('F', 60)


SELECT name, [COUNT],  
    CEILING([COUNT] * 10.0 / (SELECT MAX([Count])  - MIN([Count]) + 1 FROM #Scale)) AS [Scale]
FROM #scale
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d41d8/41244/0)**:

```
| NAME | COUNT | SCALE |
|------|-------|-------|
|    A |    19 |     2 |
|    B |     1 |     1 |
|    C |    25 |     3 |
|    D |   100 |    10 |
|    E |    29 |     3 |
|    F |    60 |     6 |
```

This gets you your answer where 60 becomes 7, hence 100 is 11:

```
SELECT name, [COUNT],  
    CEILING([COUNT] * 10.0 / (SELECT MAX([Count])  - MIN([Count]) FROM #Scale)) AS [Scale]
FROM #scale
```

Comment: Thank you Steve! This helped med a lot. your right about the 100 that should be 99 in my example. I will never be as good as the database itself ;)

Answer (score 1):

```
WITH MinMax(Min, Max) AS (SELECT MIN(Count), MAX(Count) FROM Table1)
SELECT Name, Count, 1 + 9 * (Count - Min) / (Max - Min) AS Scale
FROM Table1, MinMax
```

Answer (score 1):

You can make `Scale` column a `PERSISTED COMPUTED` column as:

```
alter table test drop column Scale

ALTER TABLE test ADD
Scale AS (case when Count between 0 and 9 then 1 
               when Count between 10 and 19 then 2
               when Count between 20 and 29 then 3
               when Count between 30 and 39 then 4
               when Count between 40 and 49 then 5 
               when Count between 50 and 59 then 6
               when Count between 60 and 69 then 7
               when Count between 70 and 79 then 8 
               when Count between 80 and 89 then 9
               when Count between 90 and 100 then 10
          end
          )PERSISTED
GO
```

<kbd>[DEMO](http://rextester.com/CXV58804)</kbd>

Answer (score 1):

```
select ntile(10) over (order by [count])
```

Comment: It would be better if you provided the intuition for this query.